# How to set help_text of password fields in custom Django Allauth form?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I would like to set `help_text` for the `password1` field in my custom SignupForm (set with `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'myapp.forms.SignupForm'`).

The form works fine otherwise but I can't modify the `password1`-field since it is created when Allauth inherits from *my* SignupForm.

My `SignupForm`, where I add a checkbox and adjust a few simple things:

```
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Client

        fields = [
            'phone_number',
            'pin',
            'address',
            'zipcode',
            'city',
        ]

        widgets = {
            'phone_number': phone_number_widget,
        }

    agree_to_terms = forms.BooleanField(
        label=mark_safe(
            ugettext('I agree to the <a href="/terms">terms and conditions</a>')
        )
    )

    field_order = ['name'] + Meta.fields + [
        'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'agree_to_terms'
    ]
```

And in Allauths's `account/forms.py`:

```
class SignupForm(BaseSignupForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password1'] = PasswordField(label=_("Password"))
        if app_settings.SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE:
            self.fields['password2'] = PasswordField(
                label=_("Password (again)"))

    ...
    ...
```

Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `SignupForm` should be a subclass of the allauth `SignupForm`, that way it inherits from `BaseSignupForm` rather than the `BaseSignupForm` inheriting from your form:

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm as AllauthSignupForm
class SignupForm(ModelForm, AllauthSignupForm):
    ...
```

And in settings, set `ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'my_app.forms.SignupForm'}`.